# App se cierra al no tener conexión a internet

Tags: java, android, app

Llevo desarrollando una app y funciona correcto en lo que necesito. Es un parser de noticias. El problema ocurre cuando quiero verificar la conexión a Internet, con Internet funciona bien.

Pero me desconecto, la abro y se detiene, en el log me muestra:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main Process: com.tucuenca.com.tucuenca3, PID: 30480
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'int java.util.List.size()' on a null object reference
    at com.tucuenca.com.tucuenca3.adaptadorNoticia.getItemCount(adaptadorNoticia.java:74)
    at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.onMeasure(RecyclerView.java:2556)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17998)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5698)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1692)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:760)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:629)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17998)
    at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChildHorizontal(RelativeLayout.java:846)
    at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:512)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17998)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5698)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1692)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:760)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:629)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17998)
    at android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout.onMeasure(DrawerLayout.java:940)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17998)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5698)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:465)
    at android.support.v7.widget.ContentFrameLayout.onMeasure(ContentFrameLayout.java:135)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17998)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5698)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1692)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:760)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:629)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17998)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5698)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:465)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17998)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5698)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1692)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:760)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:629)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17998)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5698)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:465)
    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2732)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17998)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:2412)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1414)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1638)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1292)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6598)
    at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:800)
    at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:603)
    at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:572)
    at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:786)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:815)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:104)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5717)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:960)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:755)
```

Por ahora solo quería que me muestre que tiene o no acceso a Internet.

Con esta función compruebo la conexión a Internet, pero como les comentó solo quiero por ahora que me diga si hay o no conexión.

```
 ConnectivityManager cm;
    NetworkInfo ni;
    cm = (ConnectivityManager) this.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    ni = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    boolean tipoConexion1 = false;
    boolean tipoConexion2 = false;

if (ni != null) {
        ConnectivityManager connManager1 = (ConnectivityManager) this.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo mWifi = connManager1.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI);

        ConnectivityManager connManager2 = (ConnectivityManager) this.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo mMobile = connManager2.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE);

        if (mWifi.isConnected()) {
            tipoConexion1 = true;
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Wifi", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        if (mMobile.isConnected()) {
            tipoConexion2 = true;
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Mobil", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        if (tipoConexion1 == true || tipoConexion2 == true) {
           /* Estas conectado a internet usando wifi o redes moviles, puedes enviar tus datos */
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Conexión a internet ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
    else {
   /* No estas conectado a internet */
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Verifique su conexión a internet ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
```

Esta es mi clase adaptadornoticia.java

```
public class adaptadorNoticia extends RecyclerView.Adapter<adaptadorNoticia.ViewHolder>  {
//private List<noticia> items;
/**
 * Interfaz de comunicación
 */
public interface OnItemClickListener {
    void onItemClick(ViewHolder item, int position);
}

private OnItemClickListener listener;

public void setOnItemClickListener(OnItemClickListener listener) {
    this.listener = listener;
}

public OnItemClickListener getOnItemClickListener() {
    return listener;
}

public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder
        implements View.OnClickListener {
    // Campos respectivos de un item
    public TextView titulo;
    public TextView fecha;
    public ImageView imagen;

    private adaptadorNoticia padre = null;

    public ViewHolder(View v, adaptadorNoticia padre) {
        super(v);

        v.setOnClickListener(this);
        this.padre = padre;

        titulo = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.titulo_noticia);
        fecha = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.precio_fecha);
        imagen = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.miniatura_noticia);

    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        final OnItemClickListener listener = padre.getOnItemClickListener();
        if (listener != null) {
            listener.onItemClick(this, getAdapterPosition());
        }
    }
}
public adaptadorNoticia(){}
@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    //return noticia.Ultimas_Noticias.get(position).getId();
    return Long.parseLong(noticia.Ultimas_Noticias.get(position).getId());
}

public int getItemCount() {
    return noticia.Ultimas_Noticias.size();
}
@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
    View v = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext())
            .inflate(R.layout.item_noticia, viewGroup, false);
    return new ViewHolder(v, this);
}


@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder viewHolder, int i) {
    noticia item = noticia.Ultimas_Noticias.get(i);
    viewHolder.titulo.setText(item.getTitulo());
    viewHolder.fecha.setText(item.getFecha());
    Glide.with(viewHolder.itemView.getContext())
            .load(item.getUrlImagen())
            .centerCrop()
            .into(viewHolder.imagen);

}
```

}

Saludos.

Comment: Muestra al menos como haces la comprobación de conexion a internet. El error ese que te sale parece ser por otra cosa: `'int java.util.List.size()' on a null object reference`

Answer (score 2):

El error desplegado en tu LogCat especifica el problema:

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method
>   'int java.util.List.size()' on a null object reference

Tratas de obtener la medida de un listado pero la instancia de la cual lo deseas obtener es nula.

```
Lista.size()
```

En tu programa el error se provoca en el metodo `getItemCount()` del `Adapter` pero es porque dentro tratas de obtener la medida del listado y el listado es nulo.